# Will running a large query on a secondary database in an availability group affect transaction performance in the primary database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, ssrs

I need to provide real-time, or almost real-time, data for SSRS and Tableau reporting. I don't want the production OLTP system to be negatively impacted by long running queries. Will running a large query on a secondary database in an availability group affect transaction performance in the primary database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Will running a large query on a secondary database in an availability group affect transaction performance in the primary database?

**It depends** on the sync mode you have used when configuring Availability group - Sync or Async !

On **Secondary replica**, **all the transactions use Snapshot Isolation level ONLY and all locking hints are ignored as well.** That's why it's important to test your workload when embracing AlwaysON.

From : [Minimizing blocking of REDO thread when running reporting workload on Secondary Replica](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2011/12/22/alwayson-minimizing-blocking-of-redo-thread-when-running-reporting-workload-on-secondary-replica/)

> While mapping reporting workload to snapshot isolation eliminates blocking between DML workload as applied by the REDO thread on the secondary replica and the read or reporting workload, it **does not eliminate the potential blocking of REDO thread when it is executing a DDL operation**.

If using

- Synchronous mode

  - Blocking issue on your secondary replica will impact performance of your queries on Primary replica. So a read workload (select) ran on secondary might blocked the redo thread from applying the changes that comes from primary replica. This means that the primary replica has to wait for changes to be applied to all secondary SYNC replica before it commits locally & might end-up in timeouts or blocking or deadlocking.

    The REDO thread can be seen on the Readable Secondary as the `DB STARTUP` command in `sys.dm_exec_requests`. If that thread is being blocked, then your read workload on the secondary could be causing an impact on the primary.

    For more details check - [Scenario 1:  Blocked REDO due to large query on the secondary replica](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2015/01/06/troubleshooting-redo-queue-build-up-data-latency-issues-on-alwayson-readable-secondary-replicas-using-the-wait_info-extended-event/)
- Asynchronous mode

  - The primary does not wait for acknowledgement from secondary. A blocking issue on secondary is just isolated to secondary wherein the redo queue will grow on the secondary until the locks are clear and the redo thread is able to apply the log blocks. This won't affect the primary replica.

Your definition of "real-time or almost real-time" needs more thought keeping in mind the sync method used, the network latency and how busy is primary replica and the log activity that needs to be transported secondary.

SQL Server 2016 has done some major enhancements in AlwaysON realm e.g.

- [Improved compression algorithms & Parallel compression of log block data](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/05/03/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-alwayson-parallel-compression-improved-algorithms/)
- [4x to 5x improvement in log block transport throughput](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/04/28/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-alwayson-log-transport-reduced-context-switches/)
- and many others - [It Just Runs Faster](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/) !

Comment: A blocked REDO thread does not impact "performance of your queries on Primary replica".  IO contention on the secondary can delay saving the log records on the secondary, which can impact commit times on the primary.  But this has nothing to do with the REDO thread.  The primary does not wait for REDO to apply the change; just for it to be written to the log file.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2011/12/22/alwayson-impact-on-the-primary-workload-when-you-run-reporting-workload-on-the-secondary-replica/

Comment: The answer mentions `So a read workload (select) ran on secondary might blocked the redo thread from applying the changes that comes from primary replica. This means that the primary replica has to wait for changes to be applied to all secondary SYNC replica before it commits locally & might end-up in timeouts or blocking or deadlocking.` - is this wrong? If so then why is it marked as an answer?

Comment: Hardening (writing the log to the replica) and Redo (applying the log to the data) are two separate processes running asynchronously with each other. The primary does not wait on the secondary to Redo before moving forward with commit status, this is only a function of hardening, which also does not wait nor really care about redo. Kin's answer is correct @variable

Comment: But the answer says : `So a read workload (select) ran on secondary might blocked the redo thread from applying the changes that comes from primary replica. This means that the primary replica has to wait......`. Why will blocking of redo (due to long running query on secondary) result in primary not being able to commit and having to wait? When records are hardened on secodnary, the primary should be able to send the commit. Why will primary wait for redo on secondary?

Comment: @variable did you happen to read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alwaysonpro/troubleshooting-redo-queue-build-up-data-latency-issues-on-alwayson-readable-secondary-replicas-using-the-wait_info-extended-event#scenario-1-blocked-redo-due-to-large-query-on-the-secondary-replica scenario ? let us know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks @KinShah - but it doesn't say that the scenario blocks queries running on primary. Where as in your answer you have mentioned that the primary replica has to wait `primary replica has to wait for changes to be applied to all secondary SYNC replica before it commits locally` - what is the reference for this please?

Comment: Redo won't block hardening on either the primary or secondary, unless there are other truncation issues that occur which could either be end user induced or bugs in the code. Otherwise, the primary needs to only wait for hardening, not for redo.

Comment: Then why is this correct answer when it says `This means that the primary replica has to wait for changes to be applied to all secondary SYNC replica before it commits locally & might end-up in timeouts or blocking or deadlocking.`

Comment: Sync commit can't move forward until the replicas acknowledge they have successfully hardened the log records. The "might end up in timeouts or blocking or deadlocking" depends on the queries used and application workload. If the primary holding locks because it's not committed yet, waiting on a secondary, then it may block other queries on the primary and cause blocking or app timeouts.

Comment: To be clear - a blocked redo thread on secondary doesn't block the log hardening on the secondary. So, a blocked redo thread on secondary will not cause blocking on primary. Whereas the answer implies that a blocked redo thread will block queries on primary. See the section under synchronous mode.